# How can I call contracts functions after it's deployed in Ropsten test net?

Tags: contract-development, ropsten

I wrote my contract in browser remix ide.It's deployed and I can transfer my tokens with online wallet.
Now how can I call contract's functions?I know I can do it with remix ide but this unconvinient because if I reload the page everything resets and I have to deploy new contract.

Comment: What wallet are you using? Do you have the contract address?

Comment: @Olivier Rikken I'm using online wallet `https://wallet.ethereum.org` with metamask chrome extension.My contract address is `0xb8666e88ff50379e8cbd105c82669dfaee2f2c9d`.This contract is in Ropsten test network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metamask is an extension that injects web3js into the browser and allows you to interact with your deployed contract. Similarly, you can implement your own custom application that connects to the Ropsten test network, with libraries like web3js or web3j. Web3j provides a very easy to use API, by auto-generating Java classes from your smart contract. Using the generated Java class you can load your already deployed contract based on its address, and then call any method you want whenever you want it.  See:https://docs.web3j.io/smart_contracts.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use "truffle console --network ropsten" to enter truffle console mode
then you can use all truffle contract schema commands

Comment: Please, can you explain more what this command does. It's a nice answer but more details should be provided for other users when they find this answer.